# What is the optimal solution for the following "Largest lexicographical string with <= K consecutive elements" problem? Why is my answer wrong?

Tags: sorting, strings

This is a simple question I ran into in a remote interview:

Given a collection of letters, permute them (or one of its subset) into a string such that:

- each letter can only be repeated for <= 11 times sequentially in the permutation
- the string is lexicographically the largest

For one case, the collection of letters is:

zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzyzzzyzzzzzzyzyzxyzzzzzzyzzxzyzyzyzzzyzyzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzyzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyyzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzyzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzyyzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzyyyyyzzzzzzzzzyzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzxzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzyyzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzyzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyzyzzzzyzzzyzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzxxzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzxyzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzxxzyzyzzyzzzzzzyzzzzxzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzyzzzzzzyzyzzzzzyzzyzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzyzzyyzyyzzzzzzyzyzzzzzzzzzyzzxzzzzyzzzyzzzyyzzzzzxzzzyyzzyzzzxyzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzyzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzxzzzzzzzzzzyzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyzyzzzyzzzzzzyzzzzzxzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyyzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzxzyzxyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzxzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzz

once converted to a multi-set, it contains:

- 17  'x'
- 114 'y'
- 869 'z'

My answer for this case is:

zzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyxyyyyyyyyyyyxyyyyyyyyyyyxyyxxxyxxxxxxxxxxx

Then the interviewer AI kept telling me that my answer is sub-optimal.

I've tried to find a better answer but it appears that none is available. Can you give a better answer for this case?

(Sorry due to the NDA I'm not allowed to write my code here, but it is a simple algorithm of greedy finite-state automaton with no backtracking + preemptive pruning)

Comment: (I can't, and not for lack of checking.)

Answer (score 3):

"permute them (or **one of its subset**) into a string"

This subset is better:

zzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyzzzzzzzzzzzyyyyyyyyyyyxyyyyyyyyyyyxyyyyyyyyyyyx**yyy**

Comment: You are right, but sorry I made a mistake about the condition, "lexicographically the largest" doesn't mean "rank the last", it means if converted to a number with base26 numeral system, it will be the largest (which means longer string are always preferred)

Comment: @tribbloid If the longer string is always preferred, then your answer is optimal my friend unless I am missing something. Also, then the statement "permute them (or **one of its subset**) into a string" is not significant in the question.

Comment: Could you add another 11 x?

Comment: @gnasher729 yes we can.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami it is not significant for the case, but sometimes you got >23 z and 1 y and nothing else

Comment: @tribbloid You are right!